# Disable radial background in chart

Tags: lightningchart

in latest version 3.10 there is radial background by default in all charts ? How do we disable it ?

```
const chartXY = lightningChart.ChartXY()
```

I am just creating like this , but there is some white radial background.. I want to remove that in all themes.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either fall back to the previous default Theme

```
const chartXY = lightningChart().ChartXY({ theme: Themes.dark })
```

or override the chart background fill style.

```
chartXY.setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({color:ColorRGBA(...)}))
```

With the latter approach you'll have to type the R, G and B values manually.

Comment: hi , in new version 4 ,again this issue , Themes.dark gives some undefined isDark error ,, I have to use Darkgold theme now ... and even 
  chart.setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(0, 0, 0, 10) })); is not changing the background color.

Comment: Themes.dark is removed in v4.0.0. Further confusion may be caused by charts having 2 overlaid backgrounds: "lcjsBackground" and "chartBackground" https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.0.0/interfaces/Theme.html#lcjsBackgroundFillStyle https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.0.0/interfaces/Theme.html#chartXYBackgroundFillStyle